# How do I create multiple servers in OpenStack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

According to official OpenStack SDK documentation I can pass *"min_count"* argument while creating a server to create more than one server. However, no matter whether I input 1, 2 or 5, OpenStack only creates one instance (without throwing any kind of exception, info etc.). I tried inputting the min_count as a string and as an int, to no avail.

So how do I create multiple instances in Python Openstack SDK? I know I can do that in a loop, but I need to create them all at once :)

Thanks in advance for all the help

```
instances_number=2
server = conn.compute.create_server(
        name=name,
        image_id=image.id,
        flavor_id=flavor.id,
        networks=[{"uuid": network.id}],
        key_name=keypair.name,
        user_data=init_script,
        has_config_drive=True,
        min_count=instances_number,
        max_count=instances_number
    )
```

Comment: I believe the min_count and max_count options are for server (anit-)affinity groups, have you tried with `count`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately "count" just doesn't do anything :/ Maybe I'd have to pass extra arguments? All this stuff has no documentation at all...

Comment: I can't really tell, I haven't used the SDK yet, I just read something related to this a few weeks ago. I guess you'll have to figure out what is required to achieve that.

Comment: Still thanks a lot man, I know it's feasible cause it's possible in Horizon :) But worst case I'll just run shell scripts for this case. I think that it works in CLI! Wishing you all the best